# finding lowest number which solves modulo arithmetic equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm having a some trouble trying to find the best solution.

Given $i,b,m \in \mathbb N$ how do I find the smallest nonnegative integer $n$ that satisfies the equation
$$i + bn \equiv 0 \mod m$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of the chinese remainder theorem, or the euclidean algorithm?

Comment: You want $b\times n\equiv i\bmod m$.

I think the most efficient solution would be to find solutions modulo each prime power $p^{\alpha}$ with $p^{\alpha}|| m$ and then find all possible solutions via the chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve for $n$ if and only if $gcd(b,m)=1$. In that case you can find $r,s$ such that $1 = rb+sm$ via euclidean algorithm. Then

$$1 \equiv rb \mod m$$ which implies $$b^{-1} \equiv r \mod m$$

Then you can just pick the least positive $n$ satisfying $$n \equiv b^{-1}(-i) \equiv -ri \mod m$$